# Localizar las bombas en buscaminas

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar el juego del buscaminas simplificado. Pregunto por pantalla el tamaño de la tabla y el porcentaje de minas que quiero que tenga. De momento se me crea una matriz con el porcentaje de minas que le he indicado como "-1" y la muestro como tabla al final del todo. ¿Como podría sumar a los valores que están en 0 las bombas"-1" que tienen cerca? Es decir, necesito que si un 0 tiene a alguno de los lados o arriba o abajo una bomba sume 1 a cada una que tenga, es decir, si tiene cerca 3 que ponga 3.

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BuscaMines {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);

        System.out.println("Inserta el lado N:");
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Inserta el lado M:");
        int m = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Inserta el porcentaje de minas:");
        int minas = scanner.nextInt();

        int percentatge = ((nm)minas)/100;

        System.out.println("Casillas del tablero: " +(nm)+".");
        System.out.println("El % de minas sera "+minas+", eso son "+percentatge+" casillas.");

        int[][] taulell = new int[n][m];

        while(minas > 0){
            int x = (int) (Math.random()m-1);
            int y = (int) (Math.random()*n-1);
            if(taulell[x][y] != -1){
                taulell[x][y] = -1;
                minas--;

            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < taulell.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < taulell.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(taulell[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```